# How to find the package of a class file in java

Tags: java, file, class, package

I'm writing a java program that works with .class files. I want to be able to read a .class file on the filesystem (with InputStream) and determine the package that it is in. That .class file might not be in a nice package directory structure, it could be lying around in some random place. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the [class file format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) - or use a library which knows how to parse class files, such as [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) and its [`ClassParser`](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html) class.

Comment: john...the link is broken  and can u paste a sample code for this

Comment: @AnilSharma: I've updated the link, through the power of searching for "class file format documentation"...

Comment: @JonSkeet - link is broken again **through the power of link only answers are bad for a reason!**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Updated the link. These days I'd just have added a comment instead... but expanding the answer wouldn't really help here. (It's not like I'm going to post the complete file format in the answer...)