# A function that grabs the name of the java class from the byte code

Tags: java, clojure

I'm looking for a library/function that takes a java `.class` file and returns the class and package name.

Are there any small libraries that do this?

Comment: Try Gloss (https://github.com/ztellman/gloss) and look at the .class spec here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Would you know if there is an internal java library for processing this?

Comment: I think this is it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408921/how-to-find-the-package-of-a-class-file-in-java

Answer (score 4):

By convention isn't the class name in the file you want to read? (name_of_class.class)  Even for sub classes, its in the text name.  It seems that you would already have to know the name of class in order to get the .class.

Not trying be a smart ass, but i guess i don't see when you would want to do this.

And to get the package, by convention it would the path the class lives in inside the jar.

Comment: I wish to load it from a byte source. There is an internal method defineClass0 that fails if the correct name is not given.