# Adding .class file to NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an assignment in school to use a given .class file in java application. The file is for reading input that the user gives. I have created a .jar file containing the .class file and added it to my project library in NetBeans, but my application does not recognise it. How do I get to use the methods provided in the file/library?

Comment: You're going to been to be more specific. What is the `.class` file; what package is the `class` in. How did you package it into a `jar`?

Comment: I don't know what package the .class is, but I packaged it in the command line.

Comment: Right. Well, the package the class is in needs to be the same as the the folder that the class is in the Jar. That's why I ask exactly how you packaged it. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7408921/2071828) might help you, or maybe your teacher gave you some information.

Comment: You could try adding the folder containing the class to your project, using the `Add JAR/Folder` option.

Comment: I can see the Lue.class file on the left, but when I try to implement this code int age=Lue.kluku(); i get error "Cannot find symbol symbol :variable Lue location: class JavaApplication4"

Comment: Do you know about imports? Have you correctly imported the class?

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know how to add this one, becayse the package in which the .class is is <default package>

Comment: Well, then you have [a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193298/2071828).

Comment: So what would be the easiest solution?

Comment: Okay, I did these steps: 1. created a new lavalibrary in netbeans 2. put the class file into: ...JavaLibrary/src/Lue/Lue.class 3. choosed the option "clean and build", and I got .jar file with package Lue 4. added the .jar to my project library and tried to put `import Lue.*;` but the program says that "package Lue does not exist".

Comment: The package of the class is named in the class file. You cannot change it without changing the class itself. Not sure that you have a solution beyond reflection.

Comment: So I uploaded the class here: http://rapidshare.com/share/0FF4B9E0B0D1F845AF4D3F52E0894BD1 can you check how the file is?

Comment: Okay, your are exactly correct. If you place _your_ code in the default package too then you should be fine. I would point out to your teacher that placing classes in the default package us **very** bad practice. It's even worse to force students trying to learn Java to do the same.

Comment: Okay, I put my mainclass in the default package, but what do I have to do with the jar file?

Comment: You can just include the folder containing the `class` file in your classpath.